# Google analytics image views

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to track an image on a website with analytics, this image is not always there and I need to know how many visitors saw this image specifically.

I saw on google documentation that i maybe can use this :

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'pageview',
  'page': '/my-overridden-page?id=1',
  'title': 'my overridden page'
});
```

But since I don't want to move my original tracker in the head i don't know what to do.
I guess i can't only put this piece of code with my image.

Ask me if you don't understand, maybe I am not clear.
Thanks.

**EDIT :**

This is for my own website, and i want to track how many times a specific image is showing.

Comment: Do you want to track within your own website or is this about an image that people might embed into their own pages (and you want to track where and how often this happens) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a way to see if the image is present in the page or not (I assume that instead of hacking your backend somehow to get this information you want to do it in javascript).

Easiest way is to give an id to that image:

```
<img src="path/to/myimage.jpg" id="datsderbunny">
```

Now you can access the image via javascript:

```
var image = document.getElementById('datsderbunny');
```

If you have jQuery in your page you can do it without id b using the "attribute contains" selector:

```
var image = $('img[src*="myimage.jpg"]');
```

(that is provided your image appears only once, else the above wil return a list of images).

Since you are using Universal Analytics you can use a custom dimension. In the admin->properties tab navigate to custom definitions and create a dimension "hasImage" at hit level (hit level means the dimension is tied to a pageview, not a visitor). I assume your new dimension has the numeric index 1.

Now modify your tracking code to look like the following:

```
var hasImage = "no"; // set a conservative default value
if(document.getElementById('datsderbunny') !== "undefined") { // if images does exist
    hasImage = "yes";
}

ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  hasImage
});
```

This tests if the image exists in the page and sets the value for the custom dimension accordingly. You can use custom dimension in custom reports or as second dimension in custom reports, and in segments.

Using virtual pageviews (as in your example code) is not a good idea, you do not want a single image to show up as a pageview.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer , that's close to what I really want. Question: can I do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/8YYNd/

Comment: Yes - that example will only send a pageview if the image does exist (which might be what you want). It should be noted that this has be placed after the image in the source code (since you can only check if the image exists after it has been loaded).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide), not Page Views for this purpose.

The most basic solution:

```
<img src="track_this.img.jpg" onload="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','images','image shown', 'image name or something']);" />
```

Comment: Can this be used on a "div" or another HTML element?

(I'm looking to track specific ad views.)

Answer (score 0):

This is other way to do it.

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X&cid=180684XXX&t=event&ec=Cursos_en_vivo&ea=Vista_del_catálogo&el=todos_los_cursos&" alt="Catálogo de cursos" ">
```

This helps when an specific element gets load. Just remove ".